# Is Excel Object Model changed in 2010?

Tags: excel, com, vb6, vba

I have a very old VB6 application, we have lost the source code. It can call excel 2003, 2007 to

1. Launch excel
2. Insert value to the new sheet cells.

I guess it use com to automate the excel, anyway we lost the source code and cannot contact the programmer.

After we upgrade the office to 2010, it cannot insert value anymore, just a blank sheet ....why?

Do anyone have the same experience as me?  old win32 program work on excel 2003/2007 , but don't work on 2010.

Attach screenshot for your reference:
when using excel 2007 , it can fill the value to sheet.
when using excel 2010 , it cannot, and the windbg show some exceptions, how can I troubleshoot it?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show some code and perhaps someone can help :).

Comment: we have lost the source codes, if we have the source codes, we prefer revise and recompile it on vb.net.....rather than keep headache on it.... anyway, is there any ways to troubleshoot it, can we trace/capture what command it send from win32 program to excel?

Comment: Made an answer to respond to you.

Comment: Never had excel for "Lunch". Is it tasty? :P Fixing the typo in your post :)

Comment: Ok. Since your code is able to launch Excel then definitely the programmer has used Late Binding and it seems like it is working. Regarding writing plain values are concerned, nothing has changed in the object model so I guess the error is somewhere else. Unfortunately, without seeing the code, my guess is as good as yours :)

Comment: How complex is the functionality of your macro? Might not be a big deal to rewrite.

Comment: our old program is Visual Basic 6 Compiled application. Not VBA or macro. we have no source code, just a setup CD. If it is written by macro or VBA, it should not a problem because the macro you said is equal to source codes.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could trace/capture, I don't think that would help you much.

Based on the simplicity of the code, you would be better off remaking it from scratch.  If it's something proprietary and very useful, you should probably consider having both versions installed at the same time, which has worked for me just fine.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but in our situation , we have no source codes, we will have large number of users will upgrade office 2010, we cannot stop users to upgrade to office 2010. In far future, we will reverse engineering it. But in the near future, we cannot stop user to upgrade office 2010, so we want to find any temporary solution to workaround it.